# Blackberry Creating New Session On Every Page

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, blackberry

I have created a mobile version of a site. It uses the CodeIgniter session to store some data. This seemed okay on Blackberry a few weeks ago but now it is making multiple sessions on every page and therefore it can't access the session where the data is saved. This works fine on the desktop and iPhone. The cookies are being saved to the Blackberry. I've got it so that it using the database to save the data.

On every page it checks to see whether the phone is touch screen to show the page differently. There is also some other data. It's all being saved but into many sessions.

It's on a subdomain - m.domain.com so I'm wondering if the domain name for the cookie might need to be set differently.

**EDIT:**

I managed to sort it out by saving the session id in a different cookie and then calling that in a query to get the info. Thank you to the person who replied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you proceed you session-id on every link and every form? if not, and the client doesn't accept cookies the session will be lost on every new page load - exactly what you're describing.

**EDIT:** to correct that, take a look at [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.session-start.php) (+ [Passing the Session ID](https://www.php.net/manual/de/session.idpassing.php)) - just add the `SID`-constant to all you links and forms, it will automatically be empty if the browser accepts cookies, so the url isn't that ugly for those clients.

Comment: What do you mean by proceed the session id? Sorry. It is accepting the cookies. I can print it out and get the id of the session. It's creating new ones on every page though.

Comment: take a look at the two links - you have to get the session-id to following pages to identify the session